# What is the correct way to link 3rd party C++ libraries in Gradle?

Tags: c++, gradle

I am currently trying to evaluate the use of Gradle C++ for a project that will have both Java and C++ components (with JNI to interface). I could just use CMake for the C++ portion, but then I would have 2 build systems which is less cleanly organized. As such, I prefer to use Gradle's C++ system in a multi-project build if it has the support that I need. The main thing that I can't find any detailed information (with code examples, etc.) is the linking of libraries. For Cmake, it is simple: use `find_package` or the pkg-config module. Every library (that I have tried to use) offers at least one of those systems. With Gradle, however, it only seems to document it for linking to C++ libraries that are built in the same project. What if, for example, I want to link to Vulkan, SFML, OpenGl, yaml-cpp, Boost, or any number of established and FOSS C++ libraries? The documentation also doesn't specify how to control dynamic or static linking.

Comment: Flease check my answer here^ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203429/additional-include-paths-and-linker-options-gradle-for-c/64822258#64822258

Comment: @S.Kadakov That isn't nearly portable enough for my use. A good linking system would work like CMake's to dynamically generate the exact flags for the particular compiler and OS. Yours will fail with any non-GCC compiler (e.g. MSVC) and will fail if the libraries have a weird name, as the case on some Linux distributions and on Windows. While building on one Linux distribution is sometimes sufficient, it's obviously better to not have that constraint if possible, such as by using CMake.

Comment: You may define toolchain-specific compiler options as shown.