# Additional include paths and linker options Gradle for C++

Tags: c++, gradle, build-system, conan

I was trying to use Gradle to compile a C++ project, but I can't find the way of declaring what additional include paths I want at compile time, and what additional libraries at link time.
I've seen solutions involving `model { }` inside project (I don't remember exactly). (But didn't work, Gradle complains all the time about non existing function.)

Also does not seem to be a clear or simple way to add Conan dependencies to a Gradle project yet. That leaves me compiling libraries on my own and then adding to the build system, but again, I can't find the way.

I've been looking in the docs for the answer, but all I find is about adding maven dependencies (But GLFW, GLEW and DearIMGUI aren't on Maven I guess...).

Any quirk? How Can I possibly just register additional includes/link files?

My `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("cpp-application")
}

tasks.register("runDebug") {
    doLast {
        exec {
            executable = "./build/exe/main/debug/my-app.exe"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think for gradle you might want to implement a custom generator, as support for Gradle is not built-in. There are the generic ``json`` generator, that will dump the necessary information in a json file, and you can get it from there. Is this what you are looking for? This blog post can help with new integrations: https://blog.conan.io/2019/07/24/C++-build-systems-new-integrations-in-Conan-package-manager.html

Comment: @drodri Actually I was looking the other way round, but if that could work, it would be fine for me. I'll look for conan integrations, and see what I find. ~Thanks!

Comment: What do you think, should we write to the developers of such important native libs such GLFW/GLEW for them to publish them on maven maybe? I haven't found a single native lib there actually...

Comment: @MilTy That could be very interesting, always using their own way of resolving dependencies is nice, instead of having to make a hack.

Answer (score 2):

After 5 hours of searching, I finally found a solution to build QT application with Gradle. Thanks to @s-kadakov.

```
plugins {
    id 'cpp-application'
    id 'cpp-unit-test'
}

application {
    targetMachines.add(machines.linux.x86_64)
}

tasks.withType(CppCompile).configureEach {
    compilerArgs.add '-fPIC'
    includes {
        '/usr/include/qt'
    }

    compilerArgs.addAll toolChain.map { toolChain ->
        if (toolChain in [ Gcc, Clang ]) {
            return ['-O2', '-fno-access-control']
        } else if (toolChain in VisualCpp) {
            return ['/Zi']
        }
        return []
    }
}

tasks.withType(LinkExecutable).configureEach {
    linkerArgs.add '-v'

    linkerArgs.add '-lQt5Core'
    linkerArgs.add '-lQt5Widgets'
    linkerArgs.add '-lQt5Gui'

}
```

I hope this helps for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using Gradle 6.7 you may do something like that:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample C++ project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Building C++ applications and libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/building_cpp_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the cpp-application plugin to add support for building C++ executables
    id 'cpp-application'
}

// Set the target operating system and architecture for this application
application {
    targetMachines.add(machines.linux.x86_64)
    
    // You may add extra private headrs 
    //privateHeaders {
    //  from('src/headers')
    //}    
}

// Some compiler configuration
tasks.withType(CppCompile).configureEach {
    // Define a preprocessor macro for every binary
    macros.put("NDEBUG", null)

    // Define a compiler options
    compilerArgs.add '-W3'

    // You may add extra include path 
    // as of -I<path> option 
    //compilerArgs.add '-I/usr/local/include/foo'
    
    // ... or even as list of extra paths
    includes {
        '/usr/local/include/foo'
    }

    // Define toolchain-specific compiler options
    compilerArgs.addAll toolChain.map { toolChain ->
        if (toolChain in [ Gcc, Clang ]) {
            return ['-O2', '-fno-access-control']
        } else if (toolChain in VisualCpp) {
            return ['/Zi']
        }
        return []
    }
}

// Linker configuration
tasks.withType(LinkExecutable).configureEach {
    // Add verbose output to linker
    // usefull while errors
    linkerArgs.add '-v' 
  
    // Add additional libraries as simple as
    linkerArgs.add '-lm' 
    linkerArgs.add '-lfoo' 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add header directories or add compiler options; after the plugins section add an application section like this:

```
application {
  privateHeaders {
   from('src/headers')
   from('/usr/include/qt5')
   }
   // To add compiler args do the following below
   binaries.configureEach {
      compileTask.get().compilerArgs.add('-O2')
   }
}
```

I am still trying to figure how to add the libraries or linker args :(

Answer (score 0):

Using Gradle 7.4.1, this worked for my cpp-library:

```
apply plugin: 'cpp-library'

...

library {

    ...

    binaries.configureEach {
        ...
        linkTask.get().linkerArgs.add("<argument here>")
        ...
    }
}
```